# Need VBScript Code to toggle between two Webpages to copy content from one page and paste to another webpage

Tags: vbscript

I am need of VBScript code to paste the content from one IE Explorer WebPage window to another IE Explorer WebPage window.

Currently i know the Process ID.
However I am not able to switch from one webpage to another. Or you can say my control does not move from one page to another.

Comment: You should post some code, or show us what you've done for it.

Answer (score 0):

@shellbye

```
Function Bmc(abc,xyz)
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call objIE.Navigate("// SOME APLLICATION") ' #opened the Web applcation 
'# LOGGED INTO THE APPLCATION SUCCESSFULLY suing the VBScript
 For i = 0 To objIE.Document.links.Length - 1
            if objIE.Document.links(i).innerText ="Create a New Case" Then
            Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

    objIE.Document.links(i).click  '## THIS OPENS A NEW Window as link is an URL
 Exit For
      End If
End Function
```

In above, I am able to Open the new window after clicking the link i.e. at Step ##

Now I want to copy the content abc and xyz passed in the function Bmc(abc,xyz) to New Window opened through this.
However I am unable to move or us can say switch control to new window.